# TFS Get total number of changesets for a team project

Tags: tfs, count, changeset

I'm trying to find out how many changesets have been committed to a particular project.

As the changeset id increments over all projects within a collection, the id itself is not usable.

Also the various ways to search for changesets do show a complete list, but not a count of changesets.

Is there a way to get het number of changesets for a single project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to export the changesets to a .csv file, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Then you can count the number easily in a .csv file.